# Matlab + CUDA slow in solving matrix-vector equation A*x=B

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, cuda, linear-algebra

I am calculating an equation A*x=B, where A is a matrix and B is a vector, x is answer (unknown) vector.

Hardware specs:
Intel i7 3630QM (4 cores), 
nVidia GeForce GT 640M (384 CUDA cores)

Here's an example:

```
>> A=rand(5000);

>> B=rand(5000,1);

>> Agpu=gpuArray(A);

>> Bgpu=gpuArray(B);

>> tic;A\B;toc;

Elapsed time is 1.382281 seconds.

>> tic;Agpu\Bgpu;toc;

Elapsed time is 4.775395 seconds.
```

Somehow GPU is much slower... Why? It is also slower in FFT, INV, LU calculations, which should be related with matrix division.

However, GPU is much faster in matrix multiplication (the same data):

```
>> tic;A*B;toc;

Elapsed time is 0.014700 seconds.

>> tic;Agpu*Bgpu;toc;

Elapsed time is 0.000505 seconds.
```

The main question is why GPU A\B (mldivide) is so slow comparing to CPU?

UPDATED

Here are some more results when A, B (on CPU), AA, BB (on GPU) are rand(5000):

```
>> tic;fft(A);toc;
Elapsed time is *0.117189 *seconds.
>> tic;fft(AA);toc;
Elapsed time is 1.062969 seconds.
>> tic;fft(AA);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.542242 seconds.
>> tic;fft(AA);toc;
Elapsed time is *0.229773* seconds.
>> tic;fft(AA);toc;
```

Bold times are stable times. However GPU is almost twice slower. By the way, why GPU is even more slower on first two attempts? Is it compiled twice firstly?

In addition:

```
>> tic;sin(A);toc;
Elapsed time is *0.121008* seconds.
>> tic;sin(AA);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.020448 seconds.
>> tic;sin(AA);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.157209 seconds.
>> tic;sin(AA);toc;
Elapsed time is *0.000419 *seconds
```

After two calculations GPU is incredibly faster in sin calculations.

So, still, why GPU is so slow in matrix division, fft and similar calculations, though it is so fast in matrix multiplication and trigonometry? The question actually should not be like that... GPU should be faster in all these calculations because Matlab has released overlapped functions (mldivide, fft) for GPU.

Could somebody help me solve these issues, please? :)

Comment: While this isn't the exact situation as you are using a direct solver rather than a krylov subspace method, there is some interesting information over on the vienacl site under benchmarking. If you take a look at this: http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/viennacl-benchmarks.html you will notice that in almost all situations the cpu is faster than the gpu for smaller matrices, this is partially due to the nature of iterative solvers, but it is also as they say the result of "the unavoidable GPU kernel launch overheads due to PCI-Express latency" which is likely having a similar affect for you.

Comment: @johnish I'm not sure that in this case the longer time should be ascribed to GPU kernel launch overheads due to PCI-Express latency. For matrices of the same size, matrix multiplication on GPU takes 0.000505s, so I would conclude that such an overhead is < 0.000505s, while the the mldivide takes 4.775395s. I would conclude that the latencies are in this case fully masked out by the processing time which can be longer than on CPU for "small" matrices, as you observed. Untile recently, Accelereyes Jacket made a good job for such tasks, but it seems it has been incorporated in Matlab now.

Answer (score 4):

Please read how Matlab calculates the solutions. It will help you understand why GPU is slower.

I'll try say it in few words.

A*x=b becomes L*(U*x=y)=b, L*U=A

1. So Matlab makes A to L*U (This process cannot be done fully parallel
   as far as I know instead some steps can be done parallel, due to
   their nature)
2. Then Matlab solves L*y=B and finds y. (This process cannot be done
   parallel as each step requires data from previous)
3. Then Matlab solves U*x=y and finds x. (This process cannot be done
   parallel as each step requires data from previous)

So it GPU clock is slower than the CPU, and since processes cannot be done parallel, CPU is faster. And no, unless you come up with a better method (good luck!) then GPU will be always slower except in some very specific cases.

Comment: it should be noted that `mldivide` (at least in the CPU version) has different execution paths depending on the input matrix properties. But for a general non-symmetric non-triangular square dense matrix, LU factorization is indeed used: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-172BD/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-172BD

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 of the explanation is in the answer from user2230360, but your question is twofold, so I'll add a bit about the multiplication.

As noted already, the LU factorization is not very easily parallelized even if some steps can be. Matrix multiplication, however, is very much parallelizable. If you're working with these things you should be able to do matrix multiplication by hand, and then you will know that calculating the elements of the matrix C in A*B=C can be done in any order you want - hence the possibility for parallel computation. That is probably why you're seeing so lightning fast multiplication, but slow solving of linear systems. One can't be parallelized "as much as the other".